# How can I do general value type for String and Array?

Tags: json, jackson, jackson-databind

I need to parse some JSON data from a remote service.

The request and/or response documents look like this.

```
{
  "some": "...",
  "someOther": [
    "...",
    "..."
  ],
  "youDontKnow": "...",
  "mayBeThis": [
    "what"
  ]
}
```

I presume, as you can see, there will only be `string` or `array` in values.

Now, instead of mapping each fields, I want to know if there any way to work with following mapping.

```
Map<String, Object> map; // each value may be string or array
```

So that I can fetch by key and cast the value to a `String` or a `String[]`(or `List<String>`) on demand.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` you can treat all values as `List`-s.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);


MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, List.class);
Map<String, List> map = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, mapType);
System.out.println(map);
```

prints:

```
{some=[...], someOther=[..., ...], youDontKnow=[...], mayBeThis=[what]}
```

Without it you can use default behaviour which creates appropriate types:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
```

prints:

```
{some=..., someOther=[..., ...], youDontKnow=..., mayBeThis=[what]}
```

Second solution requires from you checking whether it is `List` os `String`. First solution allows you to treat every value as `List` and you have much concise solution. Third option is to create `POJO` with `List`, `String` properties and `Jackson` automatically will match and parse given `JSON`.